# PyZMQ socket's fail to send when created in function

Tags: python, sockets, events, pyzmq

With PyZMQ, when I try to create a socket inside a function and send a message with it, the message is never received.

```
context = zmq.Context()

def sender():                                          
    sock = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    sock.connect("tcp://localhost:44444")
    sock.send("status good")

sender()
```

However, if I create the socket in the global scope, it works:

```
context = zmq.Context()
sock = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
sock.connect("tcp://localhost:44444")
sock.send("status good")
```

What's even stranger, is that checking for events on the underlying file descriptor shows that an event did occur. However, checking the poll value with `getsockopt(EVENTS)` indicates that there's nothing to be read from the socket.

I've tried making the function sleep for a few seconds before exiting, so the subscriber has plenty of time to read the message before the socket is destroyed. But this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution. I forgot that with ZMQ you have to wait after connecting before sending data. A one second sleep is probably sufficient, though not robust method to use in production code.

```
context = zmq.Context()

def sender():                                          
    sock = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    sock.connect("tcp://localhost:44444")
    time.sleep(1)
    sock.send("status good")

sender()
```

Any messages sent before the connection is fully established will just be dropped.